# Add view to linear layout in background thread one at a time, not once all are done

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-view

I have a linear layout that I am adding several views to. Think linear layout of result items. It is possible for there to be up to 150 result items. Generating each view takes a bit, so I want them to show up as they become available.

Here is my current code:

```
for (final Dealership loc: locations) {
        final int x = resultNumber;

        view.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                if(loc != null && parent != null && currentLocation != null) {
                    View v = getResultView(x, loc, parent, currentLocation);

                    v.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    if(parentLayout != null) {
                        parentLayout.addView(v);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        resultNumber++;
    }
```

This works in that it runs in the background and adds all the items. The only problem is that all the views appear at once, after a few seconds. I would really like it if they appeared as soon as they were created.

Is there a way I can modify this code so that it works as desired? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like instead of a `LinearLayout`, you'll want to instead go with a **[ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)**.

A `ListView` would give you a scrolling list of elements that are backed by a `Collection` of some sort (`Array`, `List`, etc.), and you could update that list on the fly. This is helpful for when you are slowly aggregating data from an external resource.

`ListView` also does some optimizing under-the-hood, and will only render row views when they are shown on the screen. If it is taking some time to render all 150 views in your `LinearLayout`, a `ListView` would help you here as well.

Comment: I believe this might be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for sharing the info! I will spend some time coding then likely come back and accept this.